# Use shapefile as a web map?

Tags: javascript, gis, arcmap

I am wondering if it's possible to use a shapefile with point features in arcmap as a web map?

I have seen examples, however most of them project the shapefile on top of a base layer map, for example, Google maps or ESRI maps. I am purely wanting to use the shapefile as a web map that supports zoom? Is this possible? If so, how would I go about achieving this?

The only method I can think of so far is to save the shapefile as a service to arcGIS for server...

Any guidance and help will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could start off by importing the shapefile into [TileMill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/). Once you have styled the layer, you could export it as an MBTile and serve it with Mapbox.

I also found this description that you might find helpful.
http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2012/11/exploring-mapbox-stack-mbtiles-tilejson.html

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

If there aren't too many points (more than a few hundred) then you probably want to generate GeoJSON from the shapefile and display the data that way.

You can convert your shapefile to geojson with the [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org) library.

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -t_srs crs:84 [name].geojson [name].shp
```

If there are more than a few hundred points, then I'd use @andrewGeo's strategy.

Answer (score 0):

The easier thing to do would be to share the shapefile from a server like ArcGIS Server or GeoServer.  GeoServer tends to be easier to share something simple, especially if you use the Boundless Geo (http://boundlessgeo.com/).  That comes with GeoExplorer which can directly consume a shapefile from GeoServer.

Depending on the API you're using to generate the basemap, you can hardcode x/y information into it or consume a KML/KMZ.  These tend to be tedious and not great if you're doing more than just viewing static data.

If you choose the server option, beware about hosting and consuming your data on the same server.  You may run into Cross Domain issues and life becomes a little more complex then.  I believe GeoExplorer automatically bypassed any issues I had with Cross Domain, but most of the other JavaScript APIs were a little more troublesome.

Answer (score 0):

With the release of QGIS 3.8 there is new feature to generate raster MBTiles layers.  Once the layer you want to convert is setup, you can open up the Toolbox by either selecting the gear icon or by going into the processing tab on the menu bar and selecting toolbox. Then in the Processing Toolbox, drill-down into the Raster Tools section. Within this section, select the Generate XYZ tile (MBTiles) option. Then you can serve it into mapbox (currently GeoServer does support serving MBTiles as well by installing the [MBTiles extension](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/mbtiles/index.html))

[Here is a reference to this with a straight forward and well-illustrated example on how to use this new QGIS feature](https://www.fulcrumapp.com/blog/mbtiles-from-qgis/).